# Show and hide dynamically created table rows from a SELECT change

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal popup that gets filled dynamically with a table that is created from the database. It has a SELECT element that can have a variable number of elements. The value contain a season code.

As the table is created each row is given a class called "season" with the season code appended to it. The end result is that we can get a class list that looks like this:

season1
season2

etc.

Here is an example of the code:

```
<select id="seaCombo">
   <option value="1">1 - Summer 2013</option>
   <option value="2">2 - Fall 2013</option>
   <option value="3">3 - Winter 2013</option>
   <option value="4">4 - Spring 2013</option>
   <option value="5">5 - Holiday 2013</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr class="season1">
    <td>Something here</td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="season2">
    <td>Something here</td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="season3">
    <td>Something here</td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="season4">
    <td>Something here</td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="season5">
    <td>Something here</td>
  <tr>  
</table>
```

What I want is to SHOW the season that is selected in the SELECT control and hide all others. The problem is that the table and the select are dynamic. Thus, the select might only have 2 seasons listed which means the table will only have two season classes. The select might have 4 seasons listed which means the table will only have the 4 season classes.

How can I write some JQuery that will show the class for the season selected yet hide all other classes in the table?

Comment: Are the values of options 3,4 and 5 is correct?

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I edited the post to reflect the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
    $('#seaCombo').on('change', function () {
        s = this.value;
        $('tr').hide(); // first hide all rows
        if ($('.season' + s).length) { // check the row-class exists or not
            $('.season' + s).show(); // show only the seasonal row
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e4s2J/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function showProperSeason() {
        var seasonNumber = $('#seaCombo').val();  //Get the season number selected
        $('table tr').hide();   //Hide all rows
        $('.season' + seasonNumber).show(); // show only the seasonal row        
    }

    $('#seaCombo').change(showProperSeason);
    showProperSeason();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/e4s2J/3/

This way you'll initially show the selected season, and also when you change the selection.

Cheers